# convert "java label" syntax to use in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I found this part of code from decompile my android application with dextojar and jd-gui (my project was removed :(

```
void Update(Context paramContext)
{
  this.today.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  int i = this.today.get(5);
  int j = this.today.get(2);
  long l1 = (this.moharamDay.getTimeInMillis() - this.today.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000L / 60L;
  long l2 = l1 / 60L / 24L;
  int k = this.today.get(11);
  if (k == 0) {
    l2 -= 1L;
  }
  int m = (int)l2;
  int n;
  label112:
  int i1;
  int i2;
  label138:
  RemoteViews localRemoteViews;
  boolean bool;
  if (m >= 0)
  {
    if (23 - k < 0) {
      break label409;
    }
    n = 23 - k;
    i1 = this.today.get(12);
    if (59 - i1 < 0) {
      break label415;
    }
    i2 = 59 - i1;
    localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(paramContext.getPackageName(), 2130903043);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(paramContext, SettingPreference.class);
    localRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(2131361804, PendingIntent.getActivity(paramContext, 0, localIntent, 0));
    if (this.today.compareTo(this.moharamDay) >= 0) {
      break label724;
    }
    localRemoteViews.setViewVisibility(2131361812, 4);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361805, this.numberDIDs[(m / 10)]);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361806, this.numberD1IDs[(m % 10)]);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361807, this.numberHIDs[(n / 10)]);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361808, this.numberH1IDs[(n % 10)]);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361809, this.numberMIDs[(i2 / 10)]);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361810, this.numberM1IDs[(i2 % 10)]);
    if (l1 % 30L == 0L)
    {
      bool = GetAndSetIsMOrH(paramContext);
      if ((j != 8) || (i != 25) || (!bool)) {
        break label421;
      }
      localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837619);
      label360:
      localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361804, this.backgroundIDs[GetAndSetBackgroundIndex(paramContext)]);
    }
  }
  for (;;)
  {
    ComponentName localComponentName = new ComponentName(paramContext, MoharamWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext).updateAppWidget(localComponentName, localRemoteViews);
    return;
    m = 0;
    break;
    label409:
    n = 0;
    break label112;
    label415:
    i2 = 0;
    break label138;
    label421:
    if ((j == 9) && (i == 2) && (bool))
    {
      localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837612);
      break label360;
    }
    if ((j == 9) && (i == 3) && (bool))
    {
      if (GetAndSetWichM3Text(paramContext) == 0)
      {
        localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837613);
        break label360;
      }
      localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837614);
      break label360;
    }
    if ((j == 9) && (i == 4) && (bool))
    {
      int i4 = GetAndSetWichM4Text(paramContext);
      if (i4 == 0)
      {
        localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837615);
        break label360;
      }
      if (i4 == 1)
      {
        localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837616);
        break label360;
      }
      localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837617);
      break label360;
    }
    if ((j == 9) && (i == 5) && (bool))
    {
      localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837618);
      break label360;
    }
    if ((j == 9) && (i == 10) && (bool))
    {
      localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837609);
      break label360;
    }
    if ((j == 9) && (i == 13) && (bool))
    {
      int i3 = GetAndSetWichM13Text(paramContext);
      if (i3 == 0)
      {
        localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837610);
        break label360;
      }
      if (i3 != 1) {
        break label360;
      }
      localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, 2130837611);
      break label360;
    }
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361811, this.hadisIDs[GetAndSetHdisIndex(paramContext)]);
    break label360;
    label724:
    localRemoteViews.setViewVisibility(2131361812, 0);
    if (i1 == 0) {
      localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(2131361812, this.moharamBackgroundImageIDs[GetAndSetMoharamBackgroundImageIndex(paramContext)]);
    }
  }
}
```

but the android studio show syntax error for labels; how can I Correction this ?

Sorii for mi Inglish !

TANKS !!

**UPDATE :**

the error :

Undefined label: ...

Comment: What are the exact errors you are getting?

Comment: Oh  I update my post